# Can I update package.json to a version not in npm library?

Tags: json, node.js, angular, npm, package.json

I am working on a project with Font Awesome, Bootstrap 4, and Angular 4. When configuring the package.json, I picked the most recent versions of each package:

```
"jquery": "^3.3.1",
"popper.js": "^1.12.9",
"bootstrap": "^4.0.0",
"font-awesome": "^4.7.0"
```

When I wanted to include an icon to my project, I copy pasted the html directly from the Font Awesome page:

```
<i class="fas fa-cog"></i>
```

This didn't render an icon on my page, and I realized it's using a new class with the most recent version: 5.0.6

https://fontawesome.com/

I went to my package.json and looked for a more recent version, but, 4.7.0 is the most recent packaged version:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/font-awesome

I imagine not just anyone can push an update like this to the package library, but it's annoying that I cant get the most recent version.

**My question is,**

Is there an easy way to include the most recent version 5.0.6 in the package.json file... directly from GitHub, for instance? I've read a question on stack overflow that shows how to do it via cli, but not with package.json syntax.

Thanks!

Comment: The owner.   All your other questions are answered in the npm docs.

Comment: You could always include the library directly in the html head

Comment: Ultimately though, you can see the owner of the repo hasn't even made a 5.* release yet: https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/releases

Comment: Right now, the best available option to install font awesome 5 is `$ npm i --save @fortawesome/fontawesome`

Comment: @Stan I need a way to add it to my package.json so it's included in my production build